# Ubuntu 14.04 - can't find usb flash stick

Tags: linux, ubuntu, usb, usb-flash-drive, usb-storage

I have an Ubuntu 14.04 with gnome shell (I think this information may be useful) and laptop mode tools installed. I can't mount just one usb stick (OCZ ATV 8GB)

"lsusb" command:

```
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 5986:0295 Acer, Inc 
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 105b:e065  
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 09da:8090 A4 Tech Co., Ltd X-718BK Oscar Optical Gaming Mouse
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

"fdisk -l command"

```
/dev/sda1   *        2048     2050047     1024000    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda2         2050048   148850687    73400320    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda3       148850688   987711487   419430400    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda4       987713534  1595121663   303704065    f  W95 Rozsz. (LBA)
Partycja 4 nie zaczyna się na granicy bloku fizycznego.
/dev/sda5       987713536  1339121663   175704064    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda6      1339123712  1379121151    19998720   83  Linux
/dev/sda7      1379123200  1579120639    99998720   83  Linux
/dev/sda8      1579122688  1595121663     7999488   82  Linux swap / Solaris
```

"Partycja 4 nie zaczyna się na granicy bloku fizycznego." means "Partition 4 does not start on physical sector boundary" but I don't think it's neccessary in my problem. 
I've tried "sudo mount -t ntfs-3g /dev/sdb1 /media/external" with result

```
ntfs-3g: Failed to access volume '/dev/sdb1': Nie ma takiego pliku ani katalogu

ntfs-3g 2013.1.13AR.1 external FUSE 29 - Third Generation NTFS Driver
    Configuration type 7, XATTRS are on, POSIX ACLS are on

Copyright (C) 2005-2007 Yura Pakhuchiy
Copyright (C) 2006-2009 Szabolcs Szakacsits
Copyright (C) 2007-2012 Jean-Pierre Andre
Copyright (C) 2009 Erik Larsson

Usage:    ntfs-3g [-o option[,...]] <device|image_file> <mount_point>

Options:  ro (read-only mount), windows_names, uid=, gid=,
      umask=, fmask=, dmask=, streams_interface=.
      Please see the details in the manual (type: man ntfs-3g).

Example: ntfs-3g /dev/sda1 /mnt/windows

News, support and information:  http://tuxera.com
```

Nie ma takiego pliku ani katalogu means no such file or directory
Funny thing is that this stick works on my dad's PC with ubuntu 12.06 LTS
Is there any solution?

Comment: Anything related in `$ dmesg |  less -j -1 +?usb` ? *(press `n` repeatedly to move to older entries of 'usb')*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your stick does not even show up in the output of `lsusb`, which is quite worrisome. Normally, components for which a suitable driver does not exist may not work, but at least they are correctly identified and reported by `lsusb`. Also, if you google around, you will see that it is a well-known and widely available stick, even under Linux.

So the problem may reside in your USB plug. Some questions and suggestions:

1. Are you sure your USB port works? Could you test it with hardware other than the OCZ ATV?
2. Try plugging your stick into a different USB port, especially a non-USB-3.0 port (the blue ones). In the past, there was a bug that prevented USB-2.0 appliances from working when plugged into a USB-3.0 port.
3. Do the following experiment: unplug your stick, then issue the command:

   > tail -f /var/log/{messages,kernel,dmesg,syslog}

Now plug the stick in its port and monitor the output of the command. It should contain error messages, if any output is produced.

Comment: I did all you asked and even tried to tail files you asked but as I see there is no response. Looks like stick is toasted because LED blinks for split second and then there is no response at all. Now it doesn't work even or PC. I will mark your answer as correct because my problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

not intending to raise the dead here, but in case anyone doesn't check this easy to do step:

Change the port!

If you screwed up the thumbdrive(etc) and can't get it to work, try changing the usb port and/or maybe refresh or reboot the system to see if that corrects it.

eg, when I gparted a thumbdrive it was no longer readable by gparted/fdisk lsusb etc. I tried reinserting (same port) no luck.
I rebooted and switched ports and "presto magico".